# No MYSQL Connect with QT CREATOR libmysqlclient_16

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, ubuntu-14.04

I've started programming in `C++` with `Qt 5.4` but I'm having problems when making a connection with MySQL. Iseem to have problems with the driver.

> OS: Ubuntu 14.04
>   QT version > 5.1

this is my error:

```
"Can not load library /home/diana/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so : ( /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.16 : version ` libmysqlclient_16 'not found (required by /home/diana/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so ) ) "
( " QSQLITE " " QPSQL " " QPSQL7 " )
Driver not found
```

**.pro file:**

```
QT + = core gui
QT + = sql

QTPlugin + = qsqlmysql
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlDriver>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlDriverCreator>
#include <QSqlDriverPlugin>
#include <QtPluginInstanceFunction>
#include <QPluginLoader>
#include <QtPlugin>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    QPluginLoader loader("/home/diana/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so");
    loader.load();

    qDebug()<<loader.errorString();
    qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();

    if (QSqlDatabase::isDriverAvailable("QMYSQL")){

        QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "Test");
        db.setHostName("localhost");
        db.setDatabaseName("School");
        db.setUserName("root");
        db.setPassword("elchaka");

        if (db.open()){
            qDebug()<<"Conected;"
        }else{
            QSqlError mensaje = db.lastError();
            qDebug()<<mensaje;
        }
    }else{
        qDebug()<<("not found driver");
    }

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `AppPath\sqldrivers\libqsqlmysql.so` put there your SQL driver(s). Also be sure to have the correct driver. Also try `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient18`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: You still can work try update qt 5.4 and does not work apologize

Comment: I have the same problem, I am using Qt 5.5.